# How does SMTP work and is it about local port or remote port of the smtp server?

Tags: c#, email

I made an Email client in C# that works using free smtp server or Yahoo and gmail smtp server. Still I am not clear about the ports and ins and outs of how smtp and finally how internet works.

Suppose I send a mail through email client like this or like outlook using ISP's smtp server then do I use port 25 of my computer and the server receives it at port 25?

Is `smtpclient.port` in C# the port of my computer or the smtp server. Also when I use web based client like Yahoo or gmail then how smtp and its port 25 fit here where web/http uses port 80?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The port for `SmtpClient.Port` is the port to connect to on the server.

As for web mail clients - the web server will connect with a mail server, not the browser. That is, when you go to yahoo or gmail, the browser will connect using port 80 - the server code itself will connect to the email server over its network using the appropriate port.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer seems towards right direction. Can you explain it in more detail so that I will be more clear. Do we send mail using yahoo or gmail through port 80 using http and not smtp to smtp server?

Comment: @HemsharmaAcharya - No, you will not use port 80 from your application, unless you want to do browser automation. You would need to talk to the SMTP server, using whatever ports the server is configured to use.

Comment: I mean when i use yahoomail from web browser. So Yahoomail never uses smtp port on my computer?

Comment: Can you describe the process that happens starting from when I type yahoo.com in browser and logging in and sending a mail to hotmail and the mail finally reaching the hotmail to particular user's inbox. Of course in the way that answers the question we are discussing.